# SPD Workflow - Wait for Field to equal value issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity

I need to be able to use the action "Wait for field to equal value" to make the workflow wait for the user to make a change in the current item.
The field it would look at has two options, Approved and Rejected, and I would need it to proceed with either option chosen.
I attempted to run it parallel, but just as I thought it would, it waited for both options to be selected.
What I really need is the option to say "Wait for field to equal Approved OR Rejected, but that doesn't seem to be an choice.

My next thought is to make both "Approved" & "Rejected" variables that equal 1. That way if the field equals 1, then it will continue. The logic makes sense, but I don't know if this possible to do in SPD or how to do it.

Comment: HI Tried above method but i guess something not working correctly in my case as workflow does not complete. Attaching snip of my workflow. Status of my workflow does not change to "Completed" which is the last step.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrPQD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrPQD.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

out of a blog that helped me saying:

> ...By default a parallel block will wait for ALL actions to complete before it moves on. This was a stumbling block that I had run into before. However, if you right click on the block and choose “advanced properties” you can tell it to continue if a Boolean workflow variable becomes true. So for my workflow I for either approved or rejected I set a variable I called ApprovalStatusFinished to true which allows the workflow to continue without waiting for the other parallel step to also complete.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I set the Approved and Rejected in two separate steps that run parallel to each other and went to the Advanced Properties and set the CompletionCondition to a variable called "ApprovalStatus1Finished".
Do I need to plug this variable in anywhere? Based on the description, if the property evaluates to be true, then the other elements in the parallel block are cancelled. Otherwise they will be completed.

So if it is approved, shouldn't the statement equal true and cancel out the Rejected step?

Comment: Since my last comment I added a few extra things into each step and realized that the boolean workflow variable does work, but it stops at the end of each step and won't transition to the next stage of the workflow. Is this normal?

Comment: after each step? I would say: no. Stages end up in the Transition to stage area. see http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-goto-step.htm

Answer (score 0):

I also found this page that has step-by-step images and instructions on how to fix this issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3076399/sharepoint-2013-workflow-throttling-and-performance-in-sharepoint-online-and-project-online