# wait till value equals to specific value in SPD

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

referring to this article: [SPD Workflow - Wait for Field to equal value issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209833/spd-workflow-wait-for-field-to-equal-value-issue)
I wrote workflow to wait till Approval status becomes "Approved"/"Rejected". It works fine but workflow does not complete till end. Attaching snip of my workflow.Last step updtae wf status to completed is not triggering.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The workflow has problems.

"Wait for approval status to equal approved" means it will pending until the workflow is approved. if the workflow is reject, it will pending forever.

I suggest you using If else condition.

Comment: Approval status is page status and Workflow completed/in progress is different thing. I am referring https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209833/spd-workflow-wait-for-field-to-equal-value-issue as it has exact requirement which I wanted.